# Delay in Timer with 5 textboxes c#

Tags: c#, timer, textbox, delay, sendkeys

I want to create something like an auto-typer.

I got 5 textboxes, and I am using a timer.

I would like to have a 5 second "pause/delay" between the text that is send from every textbox.

This is my Timer_Tick event:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(this.txt1.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        if (txt2.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(this.txt2.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        if (txt3.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(this.txt3.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        if (txt4.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(this.txt4.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        if (txt5.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(this.txt5.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }
    }
```

When I use `timer.Interval = 5000`, my application is sending every value of ALL textboxes every 5 seconds, but I want to have a delay of 5 seconds between every textbox.

Is this possible? I don't want to use `System thread sleep`, because the application will frozen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a global variable

```
int time = 0;
```

then your code can be...

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (time%5)
        {
            case 0:
                if (txt1.Text != string.Empty)
                    SendKeys.Send(this.txt1.Text);
                break;

            case 1:
                if (txt2.Text != string.Empty) 
                    SendKeys.Send(this.txt2.Text);
                break;

            //finish the switch
        }

        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        time++;
    }
}
```

you could even use

```
this.Controls.Find("txt"+(time%5 + 1))
```

Comment: Can I get a explanation why u use %5? What is happening exactly?

Comment: `time%5` is just returning an integer, then prepending it with 'txt' so you get `txt1`,`txt2`,`txt3` etc.  Then it tries finds the control by that name

Answer (score 0):

Use 5 different timers, 1 for each or the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Start out throwing all of the textboxes into a collection:

```
private List<Textbox> textboxes = new List<Textbox>(){txt1, txt2, txt3};
```

Have a variable to keep track of the next textbox to show:

```
private int nextTextBox = 0;
```

And now to pull it all together:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = textboxes[nextTextBox];
    nextTextBox = (nextTextBox + 1) % textboxes.Count; //you can put this inside the if if that's what you want
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
    {
        SendKeys.Send(textbox.Text);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I need to define the interval?

Comment: @xVizzi Wherever you create and start the timer.

Comment: Hmm It sends 5 times the same textbox value for each textbox.

Comment: @xVizzi Then you must have multiple timers, are assigning the event handler multiple times, didn't property define the list of textboxes, didn't copy my code properly, or you have some other issue in code you haven't shown or talked to us about.

Comment: Could you please take a look: http://pastebin.com/PqnRat6J I really appreciate it :( Thanks.

Comment: @xVizzi Looking through your entire application for some problem somewhere is not what SO is here for.  The solution that I've presented is capable of solving the problem that you have described.  Unless you're able to find a problem that is specific and narrow enough to be able to easily show the code and describe the problem in an SO post, it's not appropriate for the site.  You'll need to do some initial debugging, research, and experimentation on your own to  narrow the scope of the problem.